# How to translate Custom Options (dropdown) on many different products in magento

Tags: products, ce-1.8.1.0, inline-translations

I'm having trouble finding a "easier" way how to translate Custom Options at once for many products.

[image: Custom Options]

I don't want to go to each product and use the "Choose Store View:" because there are too many products.

[image: Choose Store View:]

Is there a way where I can translate the options of the dropdowns without going thru each one?

[I'm using magento 1.8.1.0, 2 languages, my directory right now have around 7gigs]